# Escaping Characters Using Regex in Node.js and Chrome

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, google-chrome

When I run the following code in Chrome 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit)

```
var myString = "ABCD+EFGH/IJKL";
myString.replace(/\+/g,"\\+")
```

Chrome returns `"ABCD\+EFGH/IJKL"`

When I run the same code in Node.js v0.12.0, Node returns `'ABCD\\+EFGH/IJKL'` --with two backslashes.

When I run the following code in Node

```
var myString = "ABCD+EFGH/IJKL";
myString.replace(/\+/g,"\+")
```

Node returns `'ABCD+EFGH/IJKL'`

I doubt there is such a fundamental bug in Node.js So, I must be doing something wrong.

How do I get regex in Node.js to return `'ABCD\+EFGH/IJKL'` given `myString` as an input?

Comment: In Node, if you run `console.log(myString.replace(/\+/g,"\\+"))` you'll get the desired output. I think Node just isn't doing the escaping when outputting directly to the REPL.

Comment: What @idbehold said: node REPL prints `newString` as `'ABCD\\+EFGH/IJKL'` but if you do `console.log(newString)` you will see the correct answer: `ABCD\+EFGH/IJKL`.